# Extract VMDK file using power iso

Tags: linux, extract, linux-mint

I was trying to extract a vmdk file using poweriso in linux mint by using the following command,

```
poweriso extract sample-disk1.vmdk / -od /home/local/test/VMDK/extracted/
```

But, I am getting the following error ,

```
PowerISO   Copyright(C) 2004-2008 PowerISO Computing, Inc
        Type poweriso -? for help

sample-disk1.vmdk: The file format is invalid or unsupported.
```

According to the documentation [here](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/features.htm) power iso supports vmdk file,

```
Support all popular virtual disc image files, such as VMWare Virtual Disc Images(*.vmdk), VirtualBox Virtual Disc Images(*.vdi), Virtual PC Virtual Disc Images(*.vdi).
```

How can I extract a vmdk file using power iso?

Comment: How did u get sample-disk1.vmdk file? It may not be in actual file format.

Comment: It is a part of virtual machine. I renamed the file for the confidentiality.

Comment: What I mean is, are there multiple vmdk files? It will happen, if you created virtual machine as thin provisioning;  I would recommend to use qemu-img to convert than image to raw disk and then make use of powerISO.  Try to bring up the image after converting it to raw disk; This will give more confidence for you before you go on powerISO.

Comment: i have an vmdk file, iso file and an mf file in my directory. I want to extract and see the content of vmdk file.

Comment: Can you try guestfish instead of powerISO; GuestFish is Linux utility to extract the virtual disk like qcow2, raw, vmdk;  And do you have multiple vmdk files in the directory? or only one vmdk file?

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded and installed "libguestfs-tools". Please share the command to extract VMDK file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108878/discussion-between-kajal-and-viswesn).

Comment: I couldn't join the chat room during that time and I hope this will answer your question that you asked in the chat room https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1130189

Answer (score 2):

I am providing information which I used to mount the qcow2 image and I hope the same will apply for vmdk too.

**Installation of GuestFish**

```
$> apt-get install libguestfs-tools
```

**Mount qcow2 image**

```
$> guestfish
Welcome to guestfish, the guest filesystem shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems and disk images.

Type: 'help' for help on commands
'man' to read the manual
'quit' to quit the shell

><fs> add vAP.qcow2
><fs> run
><fs> list-filesystems 
   /dev/sda1: ext2
   /dev/sda2: ext2
   /dev/sda3: ext2
   /dev/sda4: reiserfs
><fs> mount /dev/sda2 /
><fs> ls /
     .ash_history
     .rnd
     .ssh
     ash_env
     bin
     boot
     bzImage
     custom
     defaults
     dev
><fs> umount /
><fs> exit
```

You can make use of copy-in and copy-out to copy files from vmdk to host and vice versa